# Pairwise multiplier list arguments Python

Tags: python, arraylist, pairwise

I'm trying to write a pairwise multiplier function which takes two arguments, both being lists. pairwise_multiply should return a new list with each of the elements in the two input lists multiplied together in a pairwise fashion. e.g.

```
result = pairwise_multiply([1, 2], [3, 4])
print(result)

> [3, 8]
```

This is my current function but I keep getting syntax errors:

```
def pairwise_multiply([l1], [l2]):
  i = 0
  while 1 <= len(l1):
    lst = int(l1[i] * l2[i])
    i = i + 1
  return lst
```

Comment: There are a lot of syntax and logic errors. `while 1 <= len(l1)` you mean `i`, not `1`, right? Otherwise you will have an infinite loop. Also, you overwrite `lst` in every iteration. Your function will only return (if at all)  the result of the last multiplication

Comment: `pairwise_multiply([l1], [l2])` these are not valid python identifiers, you just want `pairwise_multiply(l1, l2)` -- this isn't haskell

Answer (score 3):

In your code here -

```
def pairwise_multiply([l1], [l2]):
```

You don't need square brackets to pass lists as arguments. Replace it with -

```
def pairwise_multiply(l1, l2):
```

Another implementation, more *pythonic* would be to use list comprehension with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) -

```
[i*j for i, j in zip(l1, l2)]
```

What [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) does is (from official documentation)-

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>
> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted. With a single iterable argument, it returns an iterator of 1-tuples

Comment: That may solve the problem but you have given no explanation of `zip` or the list comprehension to a self-described beginner nor explained why their current code is wrong.

Comment: @FHTMitchell let me know if it needs any improvements further !

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax and logic errors in this snippet.

- `def pairwise_multiply([l1], [l2])` As @FHTMitchell pointed out, you <strike>should</strike> cannot not use `[...]` when naming the arguments. This should be `def pairwise_multiply(l1, l2)`
- `while 1 <= len(l1)` you mean `i`, not `1`, right? Otherwise you will have an infinite loop. Also, since Python uses zero-based indexing, `<=` should become `<`.
- You overwrite `lst` in every iteration. Your function will only return (if at all, see previous point) the result of the last multiplication.

Taking these into account, your code can be transformed to

```
def pairwise_multiply(l1, l2):
  lst = []
  i = 0
  while i < len(l1):
    lst.append(int(l1[i] * l2[i]))
    i = i + 1
  return lst
```

But it has many points of failure (for example, what if `l1` and `l2` are not the same length?), too long and not pythonic.

We can use `zip` and list comprehension like @ThatBird suggested in their answer.